# Uniq -c sort by column?

Tags: linux, shell, uniq

Can `uniq -c` only get the number of occurrences of column 2 and then sort it according the number of occurrence? Also, after sorting, I don't want to show the number of occurrences. How to do it?

Here is my example input:

```
111111111 40
222222222 50
333333333 60
111111111 40
222222222 60 
333333333 50
```

To Be:

```
222222222 50
222222222 60
333333333 50 
333333333 60
111111111 40
```

Comment: check out [ask].  what have your tried?

Comment: your output is a little bit strange ...  you can try to use the `sort` option `-r` (reverse order) and `-u` (uniq) for your result .. like `sort -k2 -r input | sort -k1 -r -u` but the output is a little bit different from yours

Comment: Your specification is not clear to me.  Suppose you had 6 extra lines `111 10`, `333 10`, `222 10`, `111 10`, `222 10`, `444 10` of input data.  Would you require 4 extra lines at the end of the output, with `444 10`, `333 10`, `222 10` and `111 10` in sequence being acceptable?  If the order of the entries in the extra material matters, what is the required order (you should have documented this)?  If the output should be something else, you need to clarify what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file 
111111111 40
222222222 50
333333333 60
111111111 40
222222222 60 
333333333 50
$ sort file | uniq -c | sort -n -t ' ' -k 1 | awk '{print $2" "$3}'
222222222 50
222222222 60
333333333 50
333333333 60
111111111 40
$
```

1. `sort file | uniq -c` gives you 3 columns in order: `num(occurences)
   col1 col2`
2. then `sort -n -t ' ' -k 1` sorts the piped input (numerically `-n` according to num(occurences))
   that is delimited by space(specified by `t` switch) according to 2nd
   column/key(`-k 2`)
3. then `awk '{print $2" "$3}'` just prints the 2nd and 3rd field
   removing the number of occurrences field.